# Time sync with NTP on Vmware Fusion VM

Tags: linux, centos, vmware-fusion, ntp

I built a Centos 6.9 VM in VMware Fusion with Synchronize Time turned off and I followed this doc:

https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/1006427?sliceId=1&dialogID=373948728&docTypeID=DT_KB_1_1&stateId=1+0+373966292

However, I still have the problem when I pause & resume the VM, the clock is still off as it doesn't resync automatically.

This is what I have:

`uname -a`

> Linux demo.bluetalon.local 2.6.32-696.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue Mar 21
>   19:29:05 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

```
ntpd --version
ntpd 4.2.6p5
ntpd 4.2.6p5@1.2349-o Thu Oct 26 10:57:32 UTC 2017 (1)
```

`/boot/grub/grub.conf`

```
default=0
timeout=5
splashimage=(hd0,0)/grub/splash.xpm.gz
hiddenmenu
title CentOS 6 (2.6.32-696.el6.x86_64)
    root (hd0,0)
    kernel /vmlinuz-2.6.32-696.el6.x86_64 ro root=/dev/mapper/vg_cdh-lv_root rd_NO_LUKS rd_LVM_LV=vg_cdh/lv_root rd_NO_MD SYSFONT=latarcyrheb-sun16 crashkernel=auto  KEYBOARDTYPE=pc KEYTABLE=us rd_LVM_LV=vg_cdh/lv_swap rd_NO_DM LANG=en_US.UTF-8 rhgb quiet clock=pmtmr divider=10
    initrd /initramfs-2.6.32-696.el6.x86_64.img
```

`/etc/ntp.conf`

```
# For more information about this file, see the man pages
# ntp.conf(5), ntp_acc(5), ntp_auth(5), ntp_clock(5), ntp_misc(5), ntp_mon(5).
tinker panic 0
driftfile /var/lib/ntp/drift

# Permit time synchronization with our time source, but do not
# permit the source to query or modify the service on this system.
restrict default kod nomodify notrap nopeer noquery
restrict -6 default kod nomodify notrap nopeer noquery

# Permit all access over the loopback interface.  This could
# be tightened as well, but to do so would effect some of
# the administrative functions.
restrict 127.0.0.1
restrict -6 ::1

# Hosts on local network are less restricted.
#restrict 192.168.1.0 mask 255.255.255.0 nomodify notrap

# Use public servers from the pool.ntp.org project.
# Please consider joining the pool (http://www.pool.ntp.org/join.html).
server 0.centos.pool.ntp.org iburst
server 1.centos.pool.ntp.org iburst
server 2.centos.pool.ntp.org iburst
server 3.centos.pool.ntp.org iburst

#broadcast 192.168.1.255 autokey    # broadcast server
#broadcastclient            # broadcast client
#broadcast 224.0.1.1 autokey        # multicast server
#multicastclient 224.0.1.1      # multicast client
#manycastserver 239.255.254.254     # manycast server
#manycastclient 239.255.254.254 autokey # manycast client

# Enable public key cryptography.
#crypto

includefile /etc/ntp/crypto/pw

# Key file containing the keys and key identifiers used when operating
# with symmetric key cryptography.
keys /etc/ntp/keys

# Specify the key identifiers which are trusted.
#trustedkey 4 8 42

# Specify the key identifier to use with the ntpdc utility.
#requestkey 8

# Specify the key identifier to use with the ntpq utility.
#controlkey 8

# Enable writing of statistics records.
#statistics clockstats cryptostats loopstats peerstats
```

The only way to sync time is to run:

`service ntpd stop;ntpd -gq;service ntpd start;date`

Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided NOT to use NTP but use Vmware Tools instead.

```
vi /etc/yum.repos.d/vmware.repo

[vmware-tools]
name=VMware Tools for Red Hat Enterprise Linux $releasever - $basearch
baseurl=http://packages.vmware.com/tools/esx/latest/rhel6/$basearch
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=http://packages.vmware.com/tools/keys/VMWARE-PACKAGING-GPG-RSA-KEY.pub

sudo yum install -y vmware-tools-esx-nox
```